# htaccess - сделать исполняемыми .ico файлы

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Пробовал прописать в .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .ico
```

, но не помогло, файл отдаётся на скачивание :(

Comment: Означает ли это, что в ico-файле у вас хранятся не изображения, а php-код?

Comment: Конечно означает :)

Answer (score 1):

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .ico

попробуй так

Comment: не помогло( файл перестал отдаваться на скачивание, просто открывается в браузере с php исходниками